# How to send array with other parameters to a web api using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

I am sending an array of integers to the web api controller method successfully using angularjs $resource custom method without params defined. When I add other parameters with an array type parameter and define it in $resource custom method then other parameters are received successfully but the array found null.
Here is the code with only array that is working fine.
**AngularJS Service**

```
 var Product_Service = $resource('api/Product/:productId', { productId: '@id' },
   {
       'update': { method: 'PUT' },
       'bulkDelete': {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'api/Product/BulkDelete',
           isArray:true
       }
    }
```

Calling it like this (**passing directly the array)**:

```
bulkDelete: function (productIds) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                Product_Service.bulkDelete(productIds, function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }, function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
```

Server side:

```
  [Route("BulkDelete")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BulkDelete(int[] ProductIds)
    {

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

**Problem:**
I want to receive this array with another parameter but in that case array is received with value null.

```
  [Route("BulkDelete")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BulkDelete(int[] ProductIds,string hi)
    {
        //now ProductIds is null with another string hi parameter
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

angularjs service:

```
'bulkDelete': {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'api/Product/BulkDelete',
           isArray:true,
           params:{
               productIds:'@productIds',
               hi:'@hi'
           }
       }
```

Now m calling like this,

```
bulkDelete: function (productIds) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                Product_Service.bulkDelete({productIds:productIds,hi:'hi how'}, function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                }, function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
                return deferred.promise;
            },
```

Where is the problem and is that possible? If yes where I need to amend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tested and it's working

API Controller

```
[Route("api/Product/BulkDelete")]
[HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage BulkDelete(string hi, int[] productIds)
 {
            //now ProductIds is null with another string hi parameter

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
 }
```

RESOURCE

```
 var Product_Service = $resource('api/Product/:productId', { productId: '@id' },
   {
       'update': { method: 'PUT' },
       'bulkDelete': {
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'api/Product/BulkDelete',
           isArray:true,
           params:{

               hi:'@hi'
           }
       }
    }
```

CALL TO API

```
var productIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Product_Service.bulkDelete({ hi:'hello' },productIds, function (response) {
console.log(response) 
});
```